# What does check_markup() actually do?

Tags: input-formats

The following code:

```
var_dump(check_markup('This is a test', 'plain_text'));
```

outputs:

```
string(22) "<p>This is a test</p>"
```

Why does it do this?

Comment: I was looking in drupal and it looks like it does this:

Display any HTML as plain text
 
Convert URLs into links
 
Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. <br> and <p>)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`check_markup()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.module/function/check_markup/7) will:

> Run all the enabled filters on a piece of text.

Since one of those filters will probably be the HTML corrector, you'll get the `<p></p>` tags wrapping your text string.

Answer (score 7):

It depends from the input filters enabled for the input format. By default, for the "Plain text" input format, they are the following ones.

[image: screenshot]

"Convert URLs into links," and "Convert line breaks into HTML" add HTML tags into the text.